# Change permalinks on move from one site to another

Tags: permalinks, redirect

I'm in the finishing stages of moving a site from Wordpress.com to a privately hosted .org installation.

I've purchased the site-redirect upgrade and this is working fine, however on the new installation I have (and would *like* to have) a different permalink structure to the one offered on .com.

I need to find a way to redirect on the new site, from the old permalink structure to the new (/%postname%-%post_id%.html).

To make things more difficult, I'm running on IIS6 (sorry) and using the Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite plugin to use .htaccess - which has a different syntax to mod_rewrite.
Docs are here: http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/doc/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the IIS rewrites will impact things, but outside of that, I would recommend:

1. Use `Dashboard -> Tools -> Export` to **export** your site content from the .com site
2. Setup the **identical permalink structure** on the .org site
3. Use `Dashboard -> Tools -> Import to **import your site content to the .org site
4. *Then* change your permalink structure

This way, you can take advantage of the built-in WordPress permalink redirection functionality.

By setting up the .org site permalink structure identically to the .com site permalink structure, when you import the content, the permalinks will initially be set up identically. That (should) allow your .com redirect plugin to redirect correctly.

Then, when you change your permalink structure on the .org site, WordPress will apply metadata in order to redirect properly from the *old* permalink structure to the *new* permalink structure. That way, the process should work like so:

1. User requests *old* permalink from .com site
2. The .com site redirects to the *old* permalink at the .org site
3. The .org site receives the request for the *old* permalink, and serves the correct, *new* permalink

Comment: Unfortunately, I imported the content using the new permalink structure and it is currently live on the new site. How would I go about rectifying the issue on a live site?

Comment: Can you *remove* the content, change the permalink structure, and then *re-import* the content?

Comment: Is that my only option? It's a pretty busy site, the client won't like the downtime!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how well it will play with IIS, but [Redirection](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/redirection/) should allow you to choose a new structure and have all existing permalinks 301 to the new structure.